# Laravel view share wont work

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have the following class

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;


class WebUser

{


    public function __construct()
    {

        $status = (object) [
            'isLogin' => (Session::get('token')? true : false),
            'isSubscribed' => $this->isSubscribed(),
            'isPlatinum' => $this->isPlatinum(),
            'isExpired' => $this->isExpired()
        ];

        View::share('thisUser',$status);

    }
```

This class will run after user is successfully signed in.

I tried to view the shared variable in view file {{$thisUser}}, giving error

```
Undefined variable: thisUser (View:
```

Comment: Are you sure that your class is being included?

Comment: @GlenSolsberry tried with the same view that get info from the same class where view::share is executed, worked fine. How can share is globally to all classes ?

Comment: It may be helpful to show a more complete example of the class that you're using. The [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#sharing-data-with-all-views) suggests that this should normally go in your AppServiceProvider (or somehow be included from there). Is that actually the case?